# SurfaceView blank when play video usinng mediaplayer

Tags: android, media-player, surfaceview

This is My code but when I start the mediaplayer it have only the sound come out and the surface have nothing shown . Why?

I have no idea on this. Do you have some code help me to learn with this.

```
    videoV = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView1);
    sh = videoV.getHolder();

    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(path, "sample2.mp4");

    sh.addCallback(this);     
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
    mp.setDisplay(sh);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to add after

```
sh.addCallback(this);
```

this

```
sh.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

In my case it was helpful.

Comment: As of Honeycomb the method setType is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Have you added the on prepared listener?  I implemented the start in that method since it is the trigger that indicates when the video is ready to be rendered.

```
sh.addCallback(this);     
mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
mp.setDisplay(sh);
mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mp.prepare();

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

`resource` is file name which you want to play and `one.two` is package name your path may as like `android.resource://package_name/raw/file_name`

```
VideoView video=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
video.setMediaController(mediaController);
//Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://play.vedio/"+R.raw.dobeernotdrugs);
video.setKeepScreenOn(true);
video.setVideoPath("android.resource://one.two/raw/"+resource);
video.start();
video.requestFocus();
```

Also take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/sharing_a_surfaceview_between_2_mediaplayer-t6766.html)

Answer (score 0):

> This could be beneficial for novice android developers or anyone who will see this.

In my case, using this snippet in `OnCreate` method helped me to find out which device can use `SurfaceView`

```
    if (
            GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_RENDERER) == null ||
                    GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VENDOR) == null ||
                    GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION) == null ||
                    GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_EXTENSIONS) == null ||
                    GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_RENDERER) == null ||
                    GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_VENDOR) == null ||
                    GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_VERSION) == null ||
                    GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_EXTENSIONS) == null) {
        // try to use SurfaceView
    } else {
        // try to use TextureView
    }
```

To find out differences between `SurfaceView` and `TextureView` see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16917013/3048424).