# What's differences between Surfaceview and TextureView?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I've been studying Android especially View system.
I have a question differences between them but there is no documents or references in my mother language. So I want to know from you guys.

Comment: may be @ChintanRathod  link helpful to you.Nice document brother +1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**TextureView**

A TextureView can be used to display a content stream. Such a content stream can for instance be a video or an OpenGL scene.

Example :
https://github.com/dalinaum/TextureViewDemo

Document:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html

**SurfaceView**

Provides a dedicated drawing surface embedded inside of a view hierarchy.

Examples :
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Using-Surface-View-for-Android-1659.php
http://blog.wisecells.com/2012/06/04/surface-view-android/

Document:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

Answer (score 10):

`SurfaceView` and `TextureView` both are inherited from android.view.View class.
However there are some structural difference between them.

When you want more control of the single drawing board, go for `SurfaceView`

- You cannot overlay two `SurfaceView`.

`TextureView` has the following advantages over `SurfaceView`:

- You can Animate, Transform and Scale a `TextureView`.

Comment: You can certainly stack two SurfaceViews if you use a FrameLayout and setZOrderMediaOverlay to true on of the surface views

Comment: Agree with @Clocker, you can use `setZOrderOnTop`. Maybe you are saying you can't add `SurfaceView` inside `SurfaceView`?

Answer (score 5):

> In addition to other answers, this could be beneficial for novice android developers or anyone who will see this.

In my case, using this snippet in `OnCreate` method helped me to find out which device can use `SurfaceView`

```
    if (
            GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_RENDERER) == null ||
                    GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VENDOR) == null ||
                    GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION) == null ||
                    GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_EXTENSIONS) == null ||
                    GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_RENDERER) == null ||
                    GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_VENDOR) == null ||
                    GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_VERSION) == null ||
                    GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_EXTENSIONS) == null) {
        // try to use SurfaceView
    } else {
        // try to use TextureView
    }
```

> Hope it helps people who develop video player apps :)

Comment: This may work, but without explanation it's magical code. I wouldn't use it since I don't understand it. What is GLES10?

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to video playback, `SurfaceView` instead of a `TextureView`.  There are some important differences:

- TextureViews behave like normal views.  SurfaceViews don't.  A SurfaceView has
  a transparent "hole" in the UI through which an independent Surface layer can
  be seen.  This Surface is sent directly to the system graphics compositor.
- Because the video is being composited with the UI by the system compositor,
  rather than the application, it can often be done more efficiently (e.g. using
  a hardware composer "overlay").  This can lead to significant battery savings
  when playing a long movie.
- On the other hand, the TextureView contents can be freely scaled and rotated
  with a simple matrix.  The SurfaceView output is limited to scaling, and it's
  more awkward to do.
- DRM-protected content can't be touched by the app (or even the system compositor).
  We have to point the MediaCodec decoder at a Surface that is composited by a
  hardware composer overlay.  The only way to do the app side of this is with
  SurfaceView.

> The MediaCodec decoder requests buffers from the Surface, passing the
> video dimensions   in as arguments.  The Surface provides buffers with
> a matching size, which means   the video data will completely cover
> the Surface.  As a result, there's no need to   use
> SurfaceHolder#setFixedSize() to set the dimensions.  The hardware
> scaler will scale   the video to match the view size, so if we want to
> preserve the correct aspect ratio   we need to adjust the View layout.
> We can use our custom AspectFrameLayout for this.   The actual
> playback of the video -- sending frames to a Surface -- is the same
> for   TextureView and SurfaceView.

Read through [Choosing a surface type section](https://exoplayer.dev/ui-components.html#choosing-a-surface-type) in exoplayer documentation for further.

Comment: Thank you. This is a highly useful answer for people weighing between SurfaceView and TextureView.

Comment: Sorry. Makes little sense to me. First sentence "When it comes to video playback, SurfaceView instead of a TextureView." Is that a suggestion or what? Don't know what you mean by 'normal'.

Answer (score 1):

**Android SurfaceView vs TextureView**

`SurfaceView` and `TextureView` can be used to from another thread

`Surfaceview`

- better performance to use in bound with UI elements
- less memory footprint

`TextureView`

- API 14
- separate window is not created(unlike Surfaceview) that is why alpha, rotation, move, transform, animate are better
- is used inside hardware accelerated mode

Answer (score 1):

A SurfaceView takes the same parameters as other views, but SurfaceView contents are transparent when rendered.

A TextureView has better alpha and rotation handling than a SurfaceView, but a SurfaceView has performance advantages when compositing UI elements layered over videos.

For more : https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-tv