# how to find out TextureView will work on an android device?

Tags: android, gpu, opengl-es-2.0, surfaceview, textureview

I'm implementing an **IPTV** project, So I have a `TextureView` that plays video. But in some cases it has no picture and only plays audio, because of some *hardware accelerating window* issues in *set top box* device.

So my question is how to find out `TextureView` will work on an android device?

And my another question is:

How to find out an android device will run `TextureView` properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest that you start by reading the [`TextureView` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html).

Comment: I've read that but we are going to buy STB for this project and we want to know that these devices will run with TextureView properly

Comment: @Code-Apprentice read my comment please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This could be beneficial for novice android developers or anyone who will see this.

In my case, using this snippet in `OnCreate` method helped me to find out which device can use `SurfaceView`

```
    if (
            GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_RENDERER) == null ||
                    GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VENDOR) == null ||
                    GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION) == null ||
                    GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_EXTENSIONS) == null ||
                    GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_RENDERER) == null ||
                    GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_VENDOR) == null ||
                    GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_VERSION) == null ||
                    GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_EXTENSIONS) == null) {
        // this device can not use TextureView
    } else {
        // this device can use TextureView
    }
```

To find out differences between `SurfaceView` and `TextureView` see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16917013/3048424).

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest you to take a look at [Google Exoplayer 2](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html)? I've been using it for an Android TV project among other things and it seems to be working really well. It accepts auth keys and a lot of formats like progressive HLS and so on.

Demo application [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demo).

Comment: Thanks for your response, we have used `Exomedia` 4.0.2 in our project.
We need to know which device is suitable for us... note that we need to minimize cost of STB device :)